# Guzzle: how to intercept a meta Refresh

Tags: page-refresh, guzzle6

I'm using Guzzle to get the HTML of a webpage that on the domain has set a meta Refresh:

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1;URL=http://www.example.com/sub_folder/" />`

Guzzle seems not intercept this kind of redirect. Is it correct? Can I configure Guzzle to follow the refresh?

Which other solutions should can I consider to solve the problem and make Guzzle follow the refresh?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: No, not with Guzzle. I think that a custom script is needed (but I don't know at which level). Currently I solved the problem by simply read the HTML an search for the `meta http_equiv`: if Refresh, I read the URL and perform a new request (in less words, I'm using a simple recursion pattern).

Comment: yes I did the same, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I created script that manyally follows such redirect. Symfony DomCrawler is great tool to extract meta and parse meta value.